# Imprimir contenido en una variable map

Tags: c++, array, bucle-for, map, imprimir

Buenas tardes programadores,

Tengo un ligero problema que no sé muy bien como afrontar. Dispongo de una variable map definida como sigue:

```
std::map<int, std::vector <double>> minimaList;
```

Una vez he rellenado el contenido de la lista y quiero imprimirlo no sé cómo proceder:

```
for (auto it = myCube.minimaList.begin(); it != myCube.minimaList.end(); ++it) {
    cout << it->first << "\t" << it->second << endl;
}
```

Este código sé que es erróneo porque no está sobrecargado el operador << para poder imprimir el elemento que es de tipo vector, sin embargo no sé cómo hacer para solucionar el problema.
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cada elemento del mapa contiene una lista de elementos. Necesitas, por tanto, dos bucles:

```
for (auto const& pair : myCube.minimaList)  // Bucle para recorrer el mapa
{
    cout << "Item :" << pair.first;
    for (auto const& value : pair.second)  // Bucle para recorrer el vector
    {
        std::cout << '\t' << value << '\n';
    }
}
```